# Multiline legend on dojo chart

Tags: javascript, css, charts, dojo

I'm creating a lot of charts on the same page with an specific width.
The problem is that only the chart respects the width, the legend don't.
Is there a way to make the legend break the line if it have the width higher than the specified.
I tried trough CSS, but it is an  with a lot of

I want to:

```
Legend1 Legend2 Legend3 Legend4 Legend5 Legend5 Legend6 Legend7
```

Became

```
Legend1 Legend2 Legend3 Legend4
Legend5 Legend6 Legend7
```

The code generated by the dojo is:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <div class="icon">.<svg />.</div>
   <label>Label content</label>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
legend{
    float:left
}
```

Comment: But what i want is to break the line when it reaches the max size, they are already one side by side, i want to break it when the max size is reached.

Comment: It is the code generated by the dojo. But i'll provide an example of what is generated.

Comment: Did you try putting it in a table with <td nowrap> legends </td> ?? Not sure about the break when max size is reached?? maybe add width to the TD??

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution and I have found it:
you can change the number of rows specifying it on horizontal attribute with a number like:

```
legend = new dojox.charting.widget.SelectableLegend({chart: chart, horizontal:3},"legend");
```

Reference: https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/10896